# Pass new object id within create controller ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-relations

I'm hoping this is easy.... =)

I've got a question object, and a favanswer object, question has_one favanswer, favanswer belongs_to question.  I've got a favanswer_id column and index in my question model,  I'm trying to pass the newly posted favanswer_id to the corresponding question objects' favanswer_id field.  Maybe it's a lot more..or less..complicated than this,.but in the favanswer_controller I have the below in the create action, and I'm just trying to figure out how to correct line 6, or whatever I need to do, because without 6 it works fine, it just doesn't update my question model...Help?

```
  1 def create
  2
  3  @answer = Answer.find(params[:answer_id])
  4  @question = @answer.question_id
  5  Favanswer.create(favanswer_params.merge(user: current_user, question_id: @question))
  6  Question.update(@question, :favanswer_id => "HOW DO I PASS THE NEW FAVANSWER ID HERE?")
  7  redirect_to question_path(@question)
  8
  9 end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the mistake you're making here is referring to the foreign key of the association directly. Instead, rely on the association as an object. When you create the `Favanswer`, pass in the `@answer.question` object and not the id. Additionally, don't pass it in to `question_id` but rather to `question`

```
def create
  @answer = Answer.find(params[:answer_id])
  @question = @answer.question
  Favanswer.create(favanswer_params.merge(user: current_user, question:     @question))
  redirect_to question_path(@question)
end
```

Rails is friendly and kind and when you assign the Question instance to the named association, it will hook it up as required, so you have no need to update the Question directly.

Answer (score 1):

`Model.create` returns an instance of the newly created Model, which is useful for what you're trying to do. That means:

```
@favanswer = Favanswer.create(favanswer_params.merge(user: current_user, question_id: @question))
Question.update(@question, :favanswer_id => @favanswer.id)
```

Will accomplish what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

smh...

figured it out =)

```
@L = Favanswer.create(favanswer_params.merge(user: current_user, question_id:    @question))
Question.update(@question, :favanswer_id => @L.id)
```

Comment: This is happening because you're referring to the question id, rather than the question.  Have you tried `@L = Favanswer.create(favanswer_params.merge(user: current_user, question: @question)` I believe if you refer to the association rather than the foreign key, Rails will Do The Right Thing.

Comment: point of clarification:  `@question = @answer.question_id` should be `@question = @answer.question` in my comment above.